Solar2d and new Xcode provisioning profile location issue
Latest MacOS update (15.0.1) required a major Xcode update (v16). I can no longer build for iOS with Solar2d (2024.3710). Keychain Access has moved from it’s documented (by Apple and Solar2d) location out of the “Application / Utilities” folder. Provisioning profiles are no longer stored where they used to be “user / library / MobileDevice / Provisioning Profiles”. Provisioning profiles have changed as follows:
In previous Xcode releases, these were installed under the path: ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles.
Starting with Xcode 16, these are installed under: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/Provisioning Profiles.
So, QUESTION: how do I point Solar2d’s iOS build at the new provisioning profile location?
Tried moving my provisioning profile from the new location and copying it into the old, but the MacOS doesn't allow it. It removes it.
----------- Solved as follows ----------
Until Solar2d updates its build options the following workaround solves this build issue:

Close Xcode
Be sure your folder ~/Library/MobileDevice is totally empty, without any files or folders inside it.
Open terminal and run: ln -s ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/"Provisioning Profiles" ~/Library/MobileDevice
As you create and install your provisioning profiles your old directory will redirect Solar2d to the new location and building in Solar2d should display your provisioning profiles.

For more on the solution thread...
https://forums.solar2d.com/t/installing-a-provisioning-profile-with-xcode-16-0-doesnt-work/356864/5
